# While I install my R package (for testing) it also re-installs all the dependencies (first time) that are already present on the system

Tags: r, cran

I have a code to track objects in the images. This code uses few function from the package clue. So clue is already installed in my system. Now I have created a package using the same code.

My description file has following lines.

> Depends: R (>= 3.4.3),
>
> clue

Because clue is already installed, I thought it will not get installed again when I use `install("mypackage")`. But to my surprise it re-installed the package. I have tried this with other installed packages, too. When I give it as "depends" or "import", it re-installs the packages. I do not want to re-install the packages if they are already on my system. Is there a way to tell R package installer to avoid re-installing packages that exist on the user's system? Some of these packages are quite large and take a lot of time to install. In addition, I have installed some packages with binary source/dependency that required me to give path for several libraries.

Comment: Check Hadley's R packages [book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html) out.

Comment: You'll need to provide more details on the package (like the full DESCRIPTION file) to get any useful feedback on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use

```
install.packages(..., dependencies = FALSE)
```

or if you use `devtools::install`:

```
install(..., dependencies = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @dash2 ! This solved my issue temporarily.  I think when I install my package first time it re-install the dependencies if there are newer version available. Because it doesn't do it every time I re-install the same package.